# Correlate Java field type and generic parameter

Tags: java, generics, reflection

Consider the following classes:

```
class A {
    B<Integer> b;
}

class B<T> {
    T t;
}
```

I need to write the follwing method:

```
Object create(Class clazz) {
    // todo
}
```

such that when `create(A.class)` is called, the returned value is an instance of A which contains an Integer in `b.t`. Naturally the method must not have any knowledge about `A` besides its class.

It is well known how to find out that the type of `b` in `A` is `B<Integer>`.

I am looking for a way to find out that the field `t` in `B` is intended to have the type of the first type parameter of `B`.

Comment: You can't look at the type of the field because of type erasure. The best you can do is examine the type of the current value `Class<?> bClass = /*whatever*/;    if (bClass.isInstance(t)) { ... } `

Comment: Java does not erase all generic type information. It is easy to find out that the type parameter of `B<Integer>` **within** `A` is `Integer`. Therefore some generic type information must be stored in class files. My question is if it is possible to correlate the type parameter and the field type of `B` and `B.t` using this information.

Comment: Michael is correct. But also, you need to understand that generics are for enhanced compile time type checking. It cannot be applied to creating objects from a Class object, other than what's already there (i.e. `T newInstance()` in Class<T>)

Comment: @MuhKarma It doesn't erase all type information but in that specific case it will. "*Therefore some generic type information must be stored*" Yes, exactly. Some. It does it in the first case and not the second case. This behaviour is well-defined and has been covered many times before, both on Stack Overflow and elsewhere. Just google "Java type erasure"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of a field that is a type parameter is assignable to `java.lang.reflect.TypeVariable`. In other words, `field.getGenericType()` returns an instance of `TypeVariable` when called for the field `B.t`.

The following complete example works for the toy case given in the question. The general case is more complicated because you must keep track of multiple levels of type parameters.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.lang.reflect.TypeVariable;

class Main {
    static class A {
        B<Integer> b;
    }

    static class B<T> {
        T t;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        A a = (A)create(A.class);
        System.out.println(a.b.t.getClass());
        // prints java.lang.Integer
    }

    static Object create(Class<?> clazz) throws Exception {
        return create(clazz, new Type[0]);
    }

    static Object create(Class<?> clazz, Type[] typeArguments) throws Exception {
        Object object;
        if (clazz == Integer.class || clazz == int.class) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            object = clazz.newInstance();
        }
        for (Field field : object.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            Type[] fieldTypeArguments = { };
            Type fieldType = field.getGenericType();
            if (fieldType instanceof TypeVariable) {
                TypeVariable<?> typeVariable = (TypeVariable<?>) fieldType;
                TypeVariable<?>[] typeParameters = typeVariable.getGenericDeclaration().getTypeParameters();
                for (int i = 0; i < typeParameters.length; i++) {
                    if (typeParameters[i] == typeVariable) {
                        fieldType = typeArguments[i];
                    }
                }
            } else if (fieldType instanceof ParameterizedType) {
                fieldTypeArguments = ((ParameterizedType) fieldType).getActualTypeArguments();
            }
            Class<?> fieldClass = null;
            if (fieldType instanceof Class) {
                fieldClass = (Class<?>) fieldType;
            } else if (fieldType instanceof ParameterizedType) {
                fieldClass = (Class<?>) ((ParameterizedType) fieldType).getRawType();
            }
            field.set(object, create(fieldClass, fieldTypeArguments));
        }
        return object;
    }
}
```